# Open AI Gym exception

Tags: python

I have repeatedly tried to get an environment to render for Open AI gym, specifically the cartpole.

Heres a picture
[showing exception in visual studio, this is also the case in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwTlf.png)

I have followed several tutorials, googled, tried using jupyter notebook because thats what one of the tutorials were using, and am just at a loss. I am quite nooby with python and using pip install and whether the correct things are on path or not so bare with me.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the error is clear.  too many values to unpack... the function (on the RHS) returns more values than the code (on the LHS) allocates for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There might be more values returned by the env.step() function.

To fix this error, you can either change the number of variables that you can use the * operator to assign all of the extra values to a single variable, like this:

`n_state, reward, done, info, *extra = env.step(action)`

This will assign the first four values returned by the function to the `n_state`, `reward`, `done`, and `info` variables, and all of the remaining values to the `extra` variable.

**Edit**

You need to specify a render mode for displaying the render.

Then you can display the render using matplotlib:

```
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

env= gym.make("CartPole-v1",  render_mode="rgb_array")
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions=env.action_space.np_random
episodes=10

for episode in range(1,episodes+1):
    state=env.reset()
    done=False
    score=0
    
    while not done:
        img = env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()        
        n_state, reward,done,info, *extra = env.step(action)
        score += reward
        
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    print(n_state)
```

Comment: Thank you! first time its actually worked, yet it did not display a window to render. Is this because i am on windows? Ive read some issues with that

Comment: you should add render mode

Comment: and then show the image using another library like matplotlib.pyplot